# Use PANDAS instead of Spark

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

Background: 
I am using Zeppelin Notebook for my analytics. Goal is to use Pandas Dataframes instead of using pySpark dataframe. Pandas has some of the statistical function which i was using. wrote .py file to test with a sample data file all the calculations and etc.

Use Case: My data files (in CSV format) have simulation data. Usually the number of columns are 45,000. Currently i am interested in reading first 20,000 columns. Number of rows are usually 200.

```py
print('1 : ' , datetime.now())
sparkDF=spark.read.csv(filePath + '/' + filename,header=True,maxColumns=50000)
print('Built sparkDF with Rows: ' , sparkDF.count() , ' Column Count: ' , len(sparkDF.columns))
print('2 : ' , datetime.now())
sparkDF1 = sparkDF.select(sparkDF.columns[0:20000])
print('Built sparkDF1 with Rows: ' , sparkDF1.count() , ' Column Count: ' , len(sparkDF1.columns))
print('3 : ' , datetime.now())
exposures = sparkDF1.toPandas()
print('Built exposures with Rows: ' , exposures.shape[0] , ' Column Count: ' , exposures.shape[1])
print('4 : ' , datetime.now())

1 :  2019-10-17 16:34:06.725326
Built sparkDF with Rows:  107  Column Count:  40002
2 :  2019-10-17 16:40:04.171931
Built sparkDF1 with Rows:  107  Column Count:  20001
3 :  2019-10-17 16:51:12.465739
Built exposures with Rows:  107  Column Count:  20001
4 :  2019-10-17 16:58:25.65423
```

Issues:

1. Pandas cannot read data files that are on HDFS.
2. To circumvent the problem, i used spark to read the file and then converted to pandas.

Time to built the data frames is considerably high.

I have to process 2900 of such files. Need some recommendations and alternates.

Comment: Read directly the `filePath`. It will read all the files together and create one dataframe, Which you can convert to pandas

Answer (score 2):

I see you're reading multiple files from a filepath. To optimize this process, what you can do is read the entire directory of `.csv` files rather than reading one file at a time (*provided your schema is the same for all files which looks like the case you have*):

```
file_path = "hdfs://path/to/multiple/files/"

df = (
        spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .options(header="true", inferSchema="true")
            .load(file_path)
    )
pdf = df.toPandas()
```

This will optimize your I/O by some amount. Even if you have 10 files or 200 files or 2900 files in the same folder, you're going to get a better speed at reading than what you would get by reading one file individually.

**Note**: The above solution will not work for nested folders.